# Cannot create an instance of "[user control]" error in designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, compiler-errors

I have created the following user control.  When I add it to a xaml window, I get the error "Cannot create an instance of "ucAppItem".  I dragged the user control onto the window from the toolbar.

XAML of user control is as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Demos.ucAppItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Width="852" Height="215">
    <Grid>

        <Label Name="lblTitle"  Content="Title" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="233,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Arial"/>


        <Image Width="40" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,80,0">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/arrow2.png"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/arrow1.png"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
        <Label x:Name="lblRun" Content="Run" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,88,35,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF2EAADC" FontSize="20">
            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF2EAADC"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#006d9e"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

XAML of window is as follows:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Demos" x:Class="Demos.Window1"
        Title="Window1" Height="487" Width="854">
    <Grid>

        <local:ucAppItem/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: worked for me. Do you have anything written in code behind of user control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, instead of `pack://siteoforigin:,,,/arrow2.png` need to write your actual `URI` and to make sure that the file exists in the project as a resource, like this ([`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)):

```
pack://application:,,,/arrow1.png
```

Secondly, trigger style for the label `lblRun`, will not work because you set this `Foreground` value locally, in WPF have a list of value precedence ([`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx)), that the local value of a higher priority than the trigger style:

```
<Label x:Name="lblRun" Foreground="#FF2EAADC" FontSize="20" ... />
```

Try to remove it `Foreground` local value and use `Style` setter:

```
<Label x:Name="lblRun" Content="Run" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,88,35,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF2EAADC"/>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#006d9e"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for those pointers! I made those changes but unfortunately it still gives the designer error!

Comment: @Rob McCabe: Strangely, for me it works. The same type of error? If you comment out `Image` control, the error will disappear?

Comment: Yea, I can now add the label back in without error. Its just the image is causing the issue.  Here's what I have:

Comment: @Rob McCabe: I think the whole thing in the `Image`. The project can not find it and throws an exception. You can see about `URI` in my answer (first link), or simply write the name of the file, like this: `<Setter Property="Source" Value="Arrow1.png" />`

Comment: <Image>
<Image.Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
<Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/arrow2.png"/>
<Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
<Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
<Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,80,0"/>
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
<Style.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/arrow1.png"/>
</Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</Image>

Answer (score 4):

@Anatoily Nikolaev - thanks for your help! Your pointer on the label fixed the issue I had with it and you were right about the image.  I'll mark your response as the answer.  It was the source that was the issue.

My label is now defined as:

```
   <Label x:Name="lblRun" Content="Run" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,88,35,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20">
        <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF2EAADC"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#006d9e"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>
```

My image is now defined as:

```
       <Image>
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource arrow2}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,80,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource arrow1}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
```

And I have resources (set in the App.xaml file), set as this:

```
<Application x:Class="demos.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="arrow1" UriSource="arrow1.png" />
        <BitmapImage x:Key="arrow2" UriSource="arrow2.png" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue with some buttons using ImageBrushes. Moving the brush resources out of UserControl.Resources and into Application.Resources as in your example turned out to be the key piece I was missing.

Comment: Sounds like you should still mark the other response as the accepted answer?